# Can an ansible task be treated as a dictionary

Tags: ansible

I have two tasks that differ by one (optional) value. Depending on where the playbook is running the optional value is either present or not. At the moment I have two copies of the task executing depending on a when clause but this is error prone as the task in question has a lot of other mandatory config and the one optional entry is lost in the mix.

```
- name: Launch configuration for prod
  ec2_lc:
    region: "{{ aws_region }}"
    name: "lc-{{ env }}-{{ type }}-{{ ansible_date_time.iso8601_micro|replace(\":\", \"-\") }}"
    image_id: "{{ ami_id }}"
    key_name: "{{ aws_key_pair_name }}"
    security_groups: "{{ sec_group_instance.group_id }}"
    instance_type: "{{ instance_type }}"
    instance_profile_name: "{{ env }}-{{ type }}"
    volumes:
      - device_name: /dev/xvda
        volume_size: 20
        device_type: gp2
        delete_on_termination: true
  register: lcprod
  tags:
    - asg
  when:
    env == "prod"

- name: Launch configuration for non-prod
  ec2_lc:
    region: "{{ aws_region }}"
    name: "lc-{{ env }}-{{ type }}-{{ ansible_date_time.iso8601_micro|replace(\":\", \"-\") }}"
    image_id: "{{ ami_id }}"
    key_name: "{{ aws_key_pair_name }}"
    security_groups: "{{ sec_group_instance.group_id }}"
    instance_type: "{{ instance_type }}"
    spot_price: "{{ admin_bid_price }}"
    instance_profile_name: "{{ env }}-{{ type }}"
    volumes:
      - device_name: /dev/xvda
        volume_size: 20
        device_type: gp2
        delete_on_termination: true
  register: lcdev
  tags:
    - asg
  when:
    env != "prod"

- name: Set lc for stg or prod
  set_fact: lc="{{ lcprod }}"
  when:
    env == "prod"

- name: Set lc for none stg or prod
  set_fact: lc="{{ lcdev }}"
  when:
    env != "prod"
```

Ideally, this example could be collapsed down into a single task (i.e. without the subsequent set_fact task) and the spot_price entry is either present or not depending on the env.

I've tried setting spot_price to null or "" without success.

Comment: Without knowing about the "omit" option mentioned in the selected answer I was assuming I would need to do something like set up a dictionary containing most of the config, optionally add the spot_price entry, and then somehow attach the dictionary to the task. I was groping my way towards this as a potential solution and the title reflected that. Can you recommend a different title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it seems like you want:

```
spot_price: "{{ (env == "prod") | ternary(omit, admin_bid_price) }}"
```

See: [Ansible Filters - Omitting Parameters](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#omitting-parameters) and [Other Useful Filters](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#id7)

Comment: As the spot price is coming in from an environment based vars file I was able to simply it a bit more to spot_price: {{ admin_bid_price | default(omit) }}

Comment: Maybe. But that's not what the question asks for. Why did you decide to notify me about the fact?